# Running Total for non date column in PowerBI matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I am running into an issue with having no values show up for certain cells in a matrix, when the should be filled in with the cumulative count. I know the issue is related to no underlying values directly in the row/column, but it still should show the cumulative count.

For example, in the picture below, column 8 for 5/31/22 should show 6, but it appears blank b/c there is no contract_id with has a date of 5/31/22 with a column 8.

My measure for the values section of the matrix is below.

I place the con_seasoning in the column part and date in the row part of the matrix. I have tried using crossjoin but am running into issues where there are values in the row/column that dont exist.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: matrix]

[image: value measure]

Comment: Please don't provide code in images/snips, instead paste and code format.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a separate table for your "seasoning' columns.
Create a new Calculated Table with (or add one manually via PowerQuery):

```
Dim Seasoning = SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(0, 17, 1), "Seasoning", [Value])
```

Then update your measure to:

```
  var MaxSeasoning = MAX('Dim Seasoning'[Seasoning])
```

Finally, use `'Dim Seasoning'[Seasoning]` for your Matrix column.

Additional, update your measure to something similar to the below to only show data when relevant...

```
Contract Count Default = 
  var maxSeasoning = MAX('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning])
  var totalCount = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Atoka Net Loss'[Id]), REMOVEFILTERS('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning]))
  var seasoningCount = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Atoka Net Loss'[Id]), REMOVEFILTERS('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning]), 'Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning] <= maxSeasoning)
  RETURN IF(totalCount > 0, COALESCE(seasoningCount, 0), seasoningCount)
```

Comment: I have tried that before and it doesnt do a cumulative count anymore. It just shows the count for each respective row/column cell. Also, it fills in 0 for cells in the matrix where data doesn't exist. Maybe i have to add in a measure that filters out where data doesnt exist.

Comment: Update, I had a connection in the data model from the Seasoning table to the Atoka Net Loss Table on seasoning, I just removed that and now the cumulative counts are showing, still need to handle the issue where data is appearing in row/column cell where it doesnt exist in the dataet.

Comment: Can you share your updated measure please. Your `var maxSeasoning` need to be looking at your `Seasoning` table. And you should be using your `Seasoning` table in the columns of the Matrix visual.

Comment: Contract Count Default = 
VAR MaxSeasoning = MAX('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning])
VAR CumulativeCount = CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Atoka Net Loss'[contract_id]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]),
        'Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning] <= MaxSeasoning
    )

)
RETURN
COALESCE(CumulativeCount, 0) 


Matrix Row: Date from Atoka Net Loss Table
Matrix Column: Seasoning column in Seasoning Table
Matrix Values: Measure above

My Seasoning table has to be dynamically updated each month, so basically it is built off the Atoka Net Loss Table in Power Query.

Comment: Try `VAR MaxSeasoning = SELECTEDVALUE('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning], MAX('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning]))`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not change anything. 

However, I did just watch a youtube video on loss triangle/customer cohort and i think i might have to do another variable with selectedvalue('Atoka Net Loss'[Date']) and somehow relate them. But the video was not doing a cumulative count, so that complicates it.

Comment: It is hard, I have it working here. Could you share a sample PBIX?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not. I am playing around with this measure below, trying to use datediff between the row (month) in the matrix and Seasoning (column) and setting where values dont exist as blank, but to no avail. Measure will be in the next comment, ran out of room,

Comment: Contract Count Default = 
VAR MaxSeasoning = MAX('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning]) //seasoning column
VAR CurrentMonthAfter = SELECTEDVALUE('Seasoning Table'[Seasoning])
VAR CurrentFirstOrderMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Atoka Net Loss'[01 End of Month Start Date])

VAR CumulativeCount = CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Atoka Net Loss'[contract_id]),
    FILTER(ALL('Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning]),'Atoka Net Loss'[con_seasoning] <= MaxSeasoning))
return
if( DATEDIFF(CurrentMonthAfter, CurrentFirstOrderMonth, MONTH) > CurrentFirstOrderMonth, Blank(),COALESCE(CumulativeCount,0))

Comment: Try `Test = 1` and see if that at least adds a one to every row/column. If not then it isn't the measure. Probably need to use a Date table for the row of your matrix instead of Date from Atoka Net Loss Table

Comment: Using a Date table for the row of the matrix causes the measure to calculate only by the column, without any respect to the row. Back to the drawing board haha. I have a feeling i will have to do some datediff on the eomonth(contract start date) and compare to the column (seasoning), which is the number of months since the contract has started

Comment: That's not true so long as you have a relationship with your date table and your Atoka Net Loss Table

Comment: Still run into the same issue with data showing up in row/columns that don't exist. When i try comparing the contract seasoning in the atoka net loss table to the seasoning column in the matrix in an if measure, i get blanks. The goal is basically a triangular net loss matrix, but it seems close to impossible with my data model.

Comment: Okay - my bad - I misinterpreted your first two comments. I've added an additional piece to the answer above.

Comment: where does the cumulative count come into play with the update? place it in the same measure. or use the update as a separate measure and place it as a filter on the visual

Comment: Update your existing measure with the one in the answer above. It basically says only do a `COALESCE(..., 0)` if the total is > 0

Comment: no luck, i ended up using dynamic sql to pivot by the seasoning and imported that into PBI as a static table. 

This is a fairly easy thing to create in excel, but PBI makes easy things impossible sometimes. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: No worries. Hard to help without having access to the PBIX. I feel we were close though.

Comment: Yes, I feel the correct combination of all, remove filters and allexcept would solve the issue. I will try to upload a sample file in the next few days, unfortunately I had a strict deadline for the initial report.